# When booking elsewhere, how do you know what Virgin Australia ticket type you will get?

Tags: tickets, luggage, bookings, flight-search-engines, virgin-australia

When booking on the Virgin Australia website, it shows there being 4 different kinds of booking classes, along with details of what is and isn't included in them (eg flexibility and bags)

[image: Virgin Australia booking]

However, it only seems to offer bookings in Australian Dollars. If I go to another travel booking website which does sell me tickets in other currencies, then they all seem to describe the flights completely differently! For this case, I see a class of `Economy - T`.

[image: Other booking]

I would guess that since it says it includes one piece of checked luggage, it would be Saver not Saver Lite, but I'm not sure?

How can I map the booking code letters like `T` that other websites show me, to the Virgin Australia friendly names like Saver, so I can be sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Velocity Frequent Flyer (Virgin Australia's loyalty program) Status Earn Fare Class table to perform the conversion - https://www.velocityfrequentflyer.com/content/Info/StatusEarnFareClass/

In that table, you can see that `T` falls under *Discount Economy* which is the other name for Saver/Saver Lite. The table does not differentiate between Saver and Saver Lite as the difference is just that one includes checked luggage, and the other does not. *Full Fare Economy* means *Flexi*. *Business* means *Business*.

If you want to see what booking class the fare is when booking on the Virgin Australia site, simply select your flights, then on the right side just under the total cost, click *View Fare Rules*. In the popup, you'll see a tab for each flight chosen. Underneath the tab, you'll see a line that starts with *Fare Basis*, e.g.

> Fare Basis: TSALE

The first letter of the fare basis is the booking class.