# After adding another bag to a Virgin Australia booking, should you get some sort of e-receipt?

Tags: tickets, paperwork, virgin-australia

Following on from my question last month - [When booking elsewhere, how do you know what Virgin Australia ticket type you will get?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38908/22751), I decided to book my Virgin Australia fare elsewhere knowing what it was, thanks everyone!, then add an extra bag on later.

Annoyingly, the Virgin Australia website didn't let me add one more piece of checked luggage online, so I had to ring them up to do it - something about it being a travel agent booking apparently? Anyway, I eventually spoke to someone helpful in their customer services team, paid the fee on my card, and added the bag.

That was all about a week ago, and I took the flight in question, with my extra bag. That all went well. The charge for the extra bag has arrived on my card too, so I did pay... But no receipt was emailed to me, neither after my phone call to add the bag, nor after the flight!

After paying to add a bag with Virgin Australia, is it normal to get some sort of receipt from them by email? Or if not, is it possible to get one from them some other way, perhaps by emailing?

(Work might cover my extra bag, but only if I give them a proper receipt for it - one line highlighted off my bank statement labelled "Virgin Australia" is unlikely to convince the accounts team to pay me back...)

Comment: I think you are entitled to a receipt after every purchase you make, no matter it's nature. So I would say get in contact with the airline and demand a receipt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not get a receipt by default from Virgin for changes made over the phone.  Having done this myself a few times (largely because we frequently travel with a dog, so everything has to be done over the phone), you will receive the initial information and ticket when booking over the phone but any further updates and charges will generally be updated in their system only.  If you have not received a receipt and require one, you will need to get in touch with Virgin again.